# Responsive grid (height issue)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Trying to make a grid of responsive squares.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZxU64/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li>4</li>
        <li>5</li>
        <li>6</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    width: 300px;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 300px;
}
li {
    width: 33%;
    height: 33vw;
    float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
}
```

Width is easy to figure out, i could also use css tables, however im trying to make perfect squares that are responsive.... only other way i know how to do this is by using **javascript** to get the width and apply it to the height. Is there a pure CSS way of making the height of each LI match the width?

Comment: So you want to get, more or less from your JsFiddle example, 6 perfect squares for responsive design?

Comment: You are taking the width based on 300px why don't make the same with the height?

Comment: I believe this is a good example of what @Danko is saying: http://jsfiddle.net/ZxU64/2/

Comment: the 300px was just an example container, the container width is always changing therefore the width + height cant be fixed widths, so yes 6 perfect squares

Comment: Have you tried to display the lists as tables?

Comment: There is no way to say `height=width` in CSS

Comment: displaying the LI's as table-cells gets the width responsive but not the heights... the height is the issue as im trying to accomplish as close to a perfect square as possible

Answer (score 1):

You can take advantage of a [little trick with margins](http://jsfiddle.net/ZxU64/6/).

Wrap the content in 0-width and 0-height elements:

```
<li><span>1</span></li>
```

and then use the following style for them:

```
li > span {
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    margin: 0 100% 100% 0;
}
```

The little known fact is that margins with percentage lengths *always* refer to the *width* of the container, even if you're setting a *vertical* margin.

Comment: @matija You're right, it isn't. Maybe I instinctively did that to create a symmetry between the horizontal and the vertical behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

You could apply the following styling attributes to maintain square containers. I would definitely recommend the use of jQuery though, it will be much more stable and far less 'hacky'.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li><p>Content</p></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
ul {
    width:100%;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
ul li {
    width:33%;
    padding-bottom:33%;
    position:relative;
}
ul li p {
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
}
```